# Is there a way to reset all the variable in a SQLite table all at once?

Tags: java, android, variables

Imagine you have hundreds of variables which values changed over time by user interaction(they are stored in the database).

Then if the user presses a button (e.g. "restore to default" button), I want to set all the variables to it's initial value.

Is there a way to do this? for example defining a default value for each variable and then call some built in method to restore them all at once?

or I have to create a method of my own and just reset all the variables one by one?

I couldn't find any thread regarding this problem.

Comment: `Is there a way to reset all the variable in android?` Wrong subject. It seems you wanna reset variables in a database.

Comment: But a database does not have variables but tables.

Comment: If it's a `database`, why not deleting the whole table?

Comment: I think I explained the problem pretty clearly in the body of the question

Comment: Please show how you store a variable in a database

Comment: I don't think that really matters. Is there a way to that based on the way I store the data in the db?

Comment: We dont know how you store data in a db so what do you expect?

Comment: Imagine the simplest way one can store data in a table using SQLite. Do you know anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As this problem is being a general and being differing from developer to developer (*different data sets and variable*), there is no offical way to solve this problem except using a method like you did.

As its really being a Database concern i would suggest you to delete the whole table or create a SQL statement to delete your concern table and recreatin it with your default data.(using some methods containing the default data).

But I would rather suggest you to use a Class with all the default value statements and methods. Also make that class Abstratct .

Comment: I though maybe there is a way like setting the default values when creating the table and then have some method for each variable to set it to it's default and then when the time comes, we just set them to their default state

Comment: I am afraid there is't one , :(

Answer (score 0):

write an if statement.
If its Java, as that's ur tag and in the android studio then have an onclick and

```
var --- = 0;
```

That's how you can do it.
There's no easier way than this.
If you could show some code I could be of more help.

Comment: I see. well that's a lot of work when you have large number of variables.